# RegEx: Check for brackets, get text inside and remove the complete bracket

Tags: php, regex

I need to check if there is a bracket in a string to extract its content:

```
if (preg_match('/(?<=\()(.+)(?=\))/is', $element, $match)) {
    array_push($result, $match[1]);
    // Remove bracket from $element
}
```

But I also want to remove the complete bracket of the $element-var. How do I do that?

```
$element = "Any text (remove that)";
// result should be:
$match[1] = "remove that";
$element = "Any text";
```

Comment: Use `preg_replace_callback` and pass a variable to the callback function if you want to store the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that brackets are not nested. Example with preg_replace_callback:

```
$result = array();
$element = preg_replace_callback('~\(([^)]*)\)~', function ($m) use (&$result) {
    $result[]=$m[1];
    return '';
}, $element);
```

Comment: What kind of RegEx do I have to use (using the same function), if I'm searching for `s.` in a string and want to get everything behind that. `Any s. text` should return `Any` for $element and `text` for $result.